# What is the meaning of symbol '|' in mathematics?

Tags: notation

I was reading a editorial for one problem and i came across one statement:

> We only need to consider submatrices with side length $sz$ such that $sz\mid X$.

[Link to full editorial](https://discuss.codechef.com/t/subsqrma-editorial/69988)

Can anyone tell me meaning of this statement.

Comment: The symbol "|" stands for "such that". It also means "divides" for example : 5|15, 3|9 etc.

Answer (score 4):

In this case, it seems to mean "divides" (which is indeed a common use of the symbol). As in

> We only need to consider submatrices with side length $sz$ such that $sz$ divides $X$.

As long as $sz$ isn't zero, it's the same as saying that the division $\frac X{sz}$ results in an integer. (The fact that $0$ divides $0$, but $\frac00$ is nonsensical makes the two statements not entirely equivalent in general.)